# How would I make a 2D colormap where each point represents a 3d angle?

Tags: python, plot

I have a HxWx3 array where the 3 denotes x,y,z co-ordinates (so it's HxW 3d points, organised in a 2D array of height H and width W). Actually I only care about the angle that x, y, z makes to the origin. I want to turn this into an RGB image of HxW that's informative. Informative means that angles close to one another should have always have similar colors, and angles far from one another should have different colors.

For context to anyone who works with computer vision: I want to do a colormap of the normal obtained from a depth map.

**EDIT** - If it makes it any easier I only need one hemisphere, not a whole sphere. So circular consistency only needs to happen in one dimension, not two (I think).

Comment: the problem here is that you can't have an angle to the origin (cause origin is a point) could you give some examples of x,y,z tuple and the angle that you want as an output

Comment: I'd interpret to *only care about the angle* as to *care about direction and not the magnitude*. So I'd normalize each xyz triple to a magnitude of one. Then simply convert the XYZ to RGB and you will have similar colors for similar directions. Maybe divide each component by 2 and add 0.5 to avoid negative RGB values.

Comment: (Btw, that's pretty much how normal maps are created; the question sounds like you want to achieve a normal map of the a buffer.)

Comment: @UlisesBussi I'm referring to some origin an a different co-ordinate frame, not the one of the image. Indeed, as MB-F says, the idea is that I could put that xyz tuple on a 3d co-ordinate system and get the two angles that are required to specify its direction

Comment: @MB-F I'm not sure that would work as then there wouldn't be the property of the map wrapping around on itself smoothly. Just consider y=0, z=0, then x would go around the equator going from black to red gradually but then the red would meet the black starting point.

Comment: I'm actually think of taking the HSV color wheel https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV (a cross section of the cylinder) and wrapping it onto a hemishphere (see my edit - I only need a hemisphere). I can then use the azimuthal angle to go around the wheel, and the elevation angle to go in/out of the wheel. Credit to you @MB-F for inspiring the idea

Comment: It seems to me that the easy way to do this is to determine the range of your x,y,z values, scale them all to (255,255,255), and then you have a perfectly ordinary RGB bitmap where close points have similar colors.

Comment: @TimRoberts see my first response to MB-F to see why I think that wouldn't work. Its not just the discontinuity btw, it's also that it would give a pretty poor visual representation of what I want. The whole equator would be varying shades of red, so that two diametrically opposite points are just a different shade of red (when they should really be different colors)

Comment: Not true.  X doesn't go AROUND the equator, X crosses through it.  X,0,0 would go from full red at one extreme, to black at the other extreme.  Right?  (X,0,0) describes a line through the center of your globe from the far eastern edge  to the far western edge.

Comment: @TimRoberts Ah you are right, I was stuck in angle land. You just made everything click I think. Silly me. Thank you!

Comment: what about normalizing xyz and use every value as a color chanel ?

Comment: @UlisesBussi yes that's what others said and I realise I was having a brain short circuit. that does indeed work.